# make some crc check code, loop for multiple file (c++)

Tags: c++, file, crc

so i have this code for checking crc file named map.spak and compare the result with my specified crc result which stored in variable "compare"

```
int main(int iArg, char *sArg[])
{
    char sSourceFile[MAX_PATH];

    memset(sSourceFile, 0, sizeof(sSourceFile));

    CCRC32 crc32;
    crc32.Initialize(); //Only have to do this once.

    unsigned int iCRC = 0;
    strcpy(sSourceFile, "map.spak");
    int compare = 399857339;

    ifstream checkfile(sSourceFile);
    if (checkfile){
        cout << "Checking file " << sSourceFile << "..." << endl;
        crc32.FileCRC(sSourceFile, &iCRC);

        if(iCRC == compare){
            cout << "File " << sSourceFile << " complete!\nCRC Result: " << iCRC << endl;
        }else{
            cout << "File " << sSourceFile << " incomplete!\nCRC Result: " << iCRC << endl;
        }
    }else{
        cout << "File not found!" << endl;
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

and now i want to make this code for multiple file
let's say the file name list stored in filelist.txt

the filelist.txt structure:

```
id|filename|specified crc
1|map.spak|399857339
2|monster.spak|274394072
```

how to make the crc check, loop for each file name

i'm not really good at c++ i only know some algorithm because i know PHP

c++ is too complicated

this is the full source included CRC source [Source Code](https://mega.co.nz/#!hZVnETjA!DtQYTnEHIu3yA8Rs7oqkyiDZlltckmUc8k2RrIueOxk)

or pastebin

TestApp.cpp [link](http://pastebin.com/jsGkidgN)

Comment: I'm guessing if you want to read from a textfile, try `fstream`.

Comment: @remyabel yes sir, but how to loop the crc check..

Comment: Read the filenames into a vector or array.

Comment: @remyabel i've try that sir,  i make some array of file name and create "for" to loop filename[x] but always error can't convert filename [x] to sSourceFile..

Comment: @FredyRommy could you provide actual code?

Comment: @igleyy i've edited the link for the source sir

Comment: @FredyRommy downloading random archives from Web is not quite a thing people like to do ;).

Comment: @igleyy edited pastebin link sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made several changes to your code. I removed guard headers since we use it only in header files. Old-fasioned memset has been replaced by operation on strings. I suspect that you need to pass `char*` to CCRC32 object hence sSourceFile is still `const char*`. I compiled code except parts with CCRC32.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "../CCRC32.H"

int main(int iArg, char *sArg[])
{
  std::vector<std::string> filenames;
  // TODO - populate filesnames (paths?)

  CCRC32 crc32;
  crc32.Initialize(); //Only have to do this once.

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < filenames.size(); i++) {
    const char* sSourceFile = filenames[i].c_str();

    unsigned int iCRC = 0;
    int compare = 399857339;    // TODO - you need to change this since you are checking several files

    std::ifstream checkfile(sSourceFile);
    if (checkfile) {

      std::cout << "Checking file " << sSourceFile << "..." << std::endl;
      crc32.FileCRC(sSourceFile, &iCRC);

      if(iCRC == compare){
        std::cout << "File " << sSourceFile << " complete!\nCRC Result: " << iCRC << std::endl;
      } else {
        std::cout << "File " << sSourceFile << " incomplete!\nCRC Result: " << iCRC << std::endl;
      }
    } else {
      std::cout << "File tidak ditemukan!" << std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```